# Wildfly:User authentication with client certificate

Tags: spring-mvc, authentication, ssl, client-certificates

I have a web application with spring security enabled. Users are authenticated with user-name and password.

Now I have to enabled authentication with client certificates. I have read a lot of articles, which could not help me get a clear picture. Most of the articles tell about enabling `https` and not about user authentication.

My set of questions :

1. Is this server specific (wildfly, tomcat, IIS.. ) ?
2. How can I access the certificate in my web application ?
3. How do I parse and set the user context from the certificate ?
4. How is this certificate generated (considering self-signed) ?

My setup :

**Server** : Wildfly 9

**Framework** : Spring MVC with Spring Security

Any leads / links to articles would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Karthik, were you able to achieve the goal? I am trying to do the same and it seems to be a beast...